# MongoDB QueryBuilder query creation using same field

Tags: mongodb, find, query-builder

I have a simple mongoDB query:

```
var qry = QueryBuilder.start
qry.and("website").exists(true)
qry.and("website").notEquals(null)
qry.and("_id").in(loc_ids)
```

website is a field in my collection, and loc_ids are a list of OIDs to each record...

The cursor does not result in any records returned from the query?  Seems like the problem is the "website" : { "$exists" : true , "$ne" : ""}...

So my question is this a valid query creation:

```
var qry = QueryBuilder.start
qry.and("website").exists(true)
qry.and("website").notEquals(null)
qry.and("_id").in(loc_ids)
```

Comment: What does the document that you are querying look like?

Comment: The document is a group of keys that define a location.  "website' is just one of those fields... website is defined as: key :website, String

Comment: And i am assuming that this is the java api for MongoDB...

Comment: So the query gives me the website portion: "website" : { "$exists" : true , "$ne" : ""}  and that seems to work just fine when I access the database using RoboMongo, but in my code I do not get any results back from the query....

Comment: Haven't worked with Java API. Can't help you any further. Try doing a .ToString() to see what is the query being sent to MongoDB from Java.

Answer (score 0):

Those commands return the current QueryBuilder object with your command appended. But you're not getting the return value, so the commands aren't appended. Chain them together like this and it should return the correct query:

`qry = qry.and("website").exists(true).and("website").notEquals(null).and("_id").in(loc_ids)`

As a side note, the Spring Data MongoDB driver is a little easier to use and makes more sense if you're familiar with how the console works.