# .and() gets ignored in QueryBuilder query

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using the QueryBuilder class to put my query together.

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^((?!Salt).)*$");
queryBuilder.put("contract").notEquals("none").and("contract").notEquals(null).and("contract").regex(regex).get();
```

My problem is that it only takes the last and condition so my query looks like this:

```
{ "contract" : { "$regex" : "^((?!Salt).)*$"}}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I also tried put an .and() instead of the put() as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24025462/3811673.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try wrapping each expression in a single **[`and()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.2/com/mongodb/QueryBuilder.html#and(java.lang.String))** operation, something like

```
BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^((?!Salt).)*$");
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder();
queryBuilder.and(
    new QueryBuilder().put("contract").notEquals("none").get(),
    new QueryBuilder().put("contract").notEquals(null).get(),
    new QueryBuilder().put("contract").regex(regex).get()
);
document.putAll(queryBuilder.get());
DBCursor cursor = getDbCollection().find(document);
```